# Kotlin Coroutines - How does a delay within a loop can be completed so fast

Tags: performance, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to run the following code.

I see in console about 8 worker threads are created and the `printThread` method after `delay` in `delayNonBlockingSumOfNumbers()` is executed parallely among different threads. I couldn't understand how the whole operation gets completed in 1-2 seconds.

I believe that a 1 second delay would actually be applied to a certain number. To be precise, 8 active threads running concurrently so total delay time would be 100000 iterations/8 Threads ~ 12500 iterations/thread or seconds.

*My question is why/how so fast. And what has happened to multiple delay blocks, please clarify my understanding, if its not right.*

I see coroutines are considered as lightweight threads,

*does this mean a thread can simultaneously process multiple delay executions?*
Why I say this is because, the output displays the same thread is being used in execution multiple times like this

[image: Coroutine in a loop execution output]

if its so, how can I debug or print the execution process of each suspended block that runs delaying execution, just like we do for threads *viz. Thread.currentThread().name*.

If I would have used Thread.sleep(1000) instead of delay, and had printed the thread, the output would display a 1 second difference between each execution. Similarly, how should I display a similar output from a coroutine execution where I can see the actual delay being processed?

```
fun delayNonBlockingSumOfNumbers(){

  printThread("Start of delayNonBlockingSumOfNumbers()")
  val deferredList = (1..100000).map {
    GlobalScope.async {
        //printThread("In Async Before Index $it")
        val timetaken:Long = 1000
        delay(timetaken)
        printThread("In Async After Delay Index $it time is -> $timetaken")
        it
    }
  }
 runBlocking {
    val sum = deferredList.sumBy { it.await() }
    printThread("End of delayNonBlockingSumOfNumbers(), sum = $sum")
 }
}

fun printThread(message:String){
  println("$message ${Thread.currentThread().name} ${Instant.now()}")
}

fun main(){
 delayNonBlockingSumOfNumbers()
 Thread.sleep(20_000)
 printThread("End of ")
}
```

Output: with the size of 1_000_000, seeing just a 3 second difference

[image: 1_000_000 coroutine example]

Comment: `delay` is NOT equal to `Thread.sleep`. It suspends the coroutine freeing up the thread for other coroutines to use. You can try logging `Thread.currentThread()` before and after `delay` and see how coroutines can continue on different one after the delay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can I debug or print the execution process of each suspended block that runs delaying execution, just like we do for threads viz. `Thread.currentThread().name`

All you have to do is enable the coroutine debug mode. As per the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#debugging-coroutines-and-threads), the easiest way to do it is with the `-ea` JVM switch.

If you run the following with `-ea`:

```
fun main() {
    measureTimeMillis {
        runBlocking {
            (1..4).forEach {
                launch {
                    println("$it, delaying in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                    delay(1000)
                    println("$it, done in ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                }
            }
        }
    }.also {
        println("Took $it ms")
    }
}
```

you should see output like this:

```
1, delaying in main @coroutine#2
2, delaying in main @coroutine#3
3, delaying in main @coroutine#4
4, delaying in main @coroutine#5
1, done in main @coroutine#2
2, done in main @coroutine#3
3, done in main @coroutine#4
4, done in main @coroutine#5
Took 1099 ms
```

> what has happened to multiple delay blocks

You started 100,000 concurrent coroutines, all of them concurrently spent their 1 second of time sleeping, and then all of them woke up after 1 second, completing your test. This is exactly the same behavior you should expect from starting 100,000 threads and making them sleep.

Just like a thread doesn't occupy a CPU core while sleeping, so a coroutine doesn't occupy a thread while sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

See this part of your code:

```
(1..100000).map {
    GlobalScope.async {
    //...
    }
}
```

so you are launching a new async coroutine for each of your 100000 elements. That is why your delays won't accumulate.